# ggplot2: starting of geom_line at different values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've tried to create a loop in order to create plots for several countries. This has been successful with the help of SO.

Now I have plots like the one below. However, I want the ETS line only start in 2005 (this is when the data starts to be >0). Basically, ETS should not just jump from zero to its value in 2005, but simply "start in the air".

Also, I would like to set the x labels to 5 year intervals.

[image]

Here is my code

```
EUETS_UN <- subset(EUETS_UN, sector != "Total")
EUETS_UN$year <-as.numeric(EUETS_UN$year)
names(EUETS_UN) <- c("Year", "Country","iso2", "Sector", "Emissions")

cols <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", 
      "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

country_2s <- unique(EUETS_UN$Country)

for(i in country_2s) {

# Color settings: colorblind-friendly palette
cols <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", 
        "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

 df_to_plot <- subset(EUETS_UN, Country == i)
 df_to_plot$Sector <- as.character(df_to_plot$Sector)

 # 
 p <- ggplot(df_to_plot) +
 geom_line(aes(x= Year,y= Emissions,group = Sector, color = Sector)) +
labs(x="Year",y="CO2 Emissions",z="",title=paste("Emissions for",i)) + 
xlim(1990,2016) +
theme(plot.margin=unit(c(.5,.5,.5,.5),"cm")) +
scale_color_manual(values = cols)+
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)

print(p)

ggsave(p,filename=paste("./",i,".png",sep=""),width=6.5, 
     height=6)

}
```

Here an excerpt of the data (if this is even needed):

```
      year country iso2      sector emissions
378   1990 Austria   AT         ETS         0
2836  1990 Austria   AT   Regulated  38264403
3100  1990 Austria   AT Unregulated  24027828
409   1991 Austria   AT         ETS         0
5100  1991 Austria   AT   Regulated  39318197
6100  1991 Austria   AT Unregulated  26581483
440   1992 Austria   AT         ETS         0
8100  1992 Austria   AT   Regulated  34823803
9100  1992 Austria   AT Unregulated  25607658
471   1993 Austria   AT         ETS         0
11100 1993 Austria   AT   Regulated  35193747
12100 1993 Austria   AT Unregulated  25593991
502   1994 Austria   AT         ETS         0
14100 1994 Austria   AT   Regulated  36260166
15100 1994 Austria   AT Unregulated  24930182
533   1995 Austria   AT         ETS         0
17100 1995 Austria   AT   Regulated  38441281
18100 1995 Austria   AT Unregulated  25764669
564   1996 Austria   AT         ETS         0
20100 1996 Austria   AT   Regulated  39489370
21100 1996 Austria   AT Unregulated  28184521
595   1997 Austria   AT         ETS         0
23100 1997 Austria   AT   Regulated  41822882
24100 1997 Austria   AT Unregulated  25630126
626   1998 Austria   AT         ETS         0
26100 1998 Austria   AT   Regulated  39063198
27100 1998 Austria   AT Unregulated  27991169
657   1999 Austria   AT         ETS         0
2910  1999 Austria   AT   Regulated  38127128
3010  1999 Austria   AT Unregulated  27493880
688   2000 Austria   AT         ETS         0
3210  2000 Austria   AT   Regulated  38294108
3310  2000 Austria   AT Unregulated  27967635
719   2001 Austria   AT         ETS         0
3510  2001 Austria   AT   Regulated  40723095
3610  2001 Austria   AT Unregulated  29667765
750   2002 Austria   AT         ETS         0
3810  2002 Austria   AT   Regulated  41130208
3910  2002 Austria   AT Unregulated  31016331
781   2003 Austria   AT         ETS         0
4110  2003 Austria   AT   Regulated  44805099
4210  2003 Austria   AT Unregulated  32959151
812   2004 Austria   AT         ETS         0
4410  2004 Austria   AT   Regulated  44921799
4510  2004 Austria   AT Unregulated  33130748
1     2005 Austria   AT         ETS  33373156
4710  2005 Austria   AT   Regulated  47032869
4810  2005 Austria   AT Unregulated  32333810
26    2006 Austria   AT         ETS  32384372
5010  2006 Austria   AT   Regulated  46050726
5110  2006 Austria   AT Unregulated  30637735
51    2007 Austria   AT         ETS  31751260
5310  2007 Austria   AT   Regulated  43754649
5410  2007 Austria   AT Unregulated  30277468
78    2008 Austria   AT         ETS  32078974
5610  2008 Austria   AT   Regulated  44826920
5710  2008 Austria   AT Unregulated  28979354
107   2009 Austria   AT         ETS  27359832
5910  2009 Austria   AT   Regulated  39430745
6010  2009 Austria   AT Unregulated  28052317
136   2010 Austria   AT         ETS  30919712
6210  2010 Austria   AT   Regulated  42836143
6310  2010 Austria   AT Unregulated  29546998
165   2011 Austria   AT         ETS  30599418
6510  2011 Austria   AT   Regulated  42148355
6610  2011 Austria   AT Unregulated  27967317
194   2012 Austria   AT         ETS  28387060
6810  2012 Austria   AT   Regulated  39494447
6910  2012 Austria   AT Unregulated  28166952
223   2013 Austria   AT         ETS  29804410
7110  2013 Austria   AT   Regulated  38573958
7210  2013 Austria   AT Unregulated  29427268
254   2014 Austria   AT         ETS  28055974
7410  2014 Austria   AT   Regulated  36311073
7510  2014 Austria   AT Unregulated  27942255
285   2015 Austria   AT         ETS  29492064
7710  2015 Austria   AT   Regulated  38003088
7810  2015 Austria   AT Unregulated  28700896
316   2016 Austria   AT         ETS  29000120
8010  2016 Austria   AT   Regulated  37651775
8110  2016 Austria   AT Unregulated  29750311
347   2017 Austria   AT         ETS  30555226
813   1990 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
8310  1990 Belgium   BE   Regulated  78614107
8410  1990 Belgium   BE Unregulated  41870292
379   1991 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
8610  1991 Belgium   BE   Regulated  79811521
8710  1991 Belgium   BE Unregulated  43733190
410   1992 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
8910  1992 Belgium   BE   Regulated  78283962
9010  1992 Belgium   BE Unregulated  44373851
441   1993 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
9210  1993 Belgium   BE   Regulated  76752290
9310  1993 Belgium   BE Unregulated  44804991
472   1994 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
9510  1994 Belgium   BE   Regulated  80647991
9610  1994 Belgium   BE Unregulated  44290197
503   1995 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
9810  1995 Belgium   BE   Regulated  80518704
9910  1995 Belgium   BE Unregulated  45564257
534   1996 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
10110 1996 Belgium   BE   Regulated  79513349
10210 1996 Belgium   BE Unregulated  50070276
565   1997 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
10410 1997 Belgium   BE   Regulated  77308936
10510 1997 Belgium   BE Unregulated  46737892
596   1998 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
10710 1998 Belgium   BE   Regulated  82610050
10810 1998 Belgium   BE Unregulated  47675059
627   1999 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
11010 1999 Belgium   BE   Regulated  77595053
11110 1999 Belgium   BE Unregulated  47150650
658   2000 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
11310 2000 Belgium   BE   Regulated  80435088
11410 2000 Belgium   BE Unregulated  46359701
689   2001 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
11610 2001 Belgium   BE   Regulated  77255899
11710 2001 Belgium   BE Unregulated  48873109
720   2002 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
11910 2002 Belgium   BE   Regulated  77914653
12010 2002 Belgium   BE Unregulated  48529972
751   2003 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
12210 2003 Belgium   BE   Regulated  78464806
12310 2003 Belgium   BE Unregulated  49488382
782   2004 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
12510 2004 Belgium   BE   Regulated  79430967
12610 2004 Belgium   BE Unregulated  49609916
2     2005 Belgium   BE         ETS  55363232
12810 2005 Belgium   BE   Regulated  77343444
12910 2005 Belgium   BE Unregulated  48294759
27    2006 Belgium   BE         ETS  54775328
13110 2006 Belgium   BE   Regulated  75869846
13210 2006 Belgium   BE Unregulated  48161044
52    2007 Belgium   BE         ETS  52795332
13410 2007 Belgium   BE   Regulated  73189198
13510 2007 Belgium   BE Unregulated  47422201
79    2008 Belgium   BE         ETS  55462028
13710 2008 Belgium   BE   Regulated  71854823
13810 2008 Belgium   BE Unregulated  48804185
108   2009 Belgium   BE         ETS  46206936
14010 2009 Belgium   BE   Regulated  61048912
14110 2009 Belgium   BE Unregulated  46593455
137   2010 Belgium   BE         ETS  50103980
14310 2010 Belgium   BE   Regulated  66648934
14410 2010 Belgium   BE Unregulated  46933097 
166   2011 Belgium   BE         ETS  46203056
14610 2011 Belgium   BE   Regulated  61319344
14710 2011 Belgium   BE Unregulated  42839297
195   2012 Belgium   BE         ETS  43006980
14910 2012 Belgium   BE   Regulated  58934979
15010 2012 Belgium   BE Unregulated  42459997
224   2013 Belgium   BE         ETS  45231176
15210 2013 Belgium   BE   Regulated  58383554
15310 2013 Belgium   BE Unregulated  43586891
255   2014 Belgium   BE         ETS  43853144
15510 2014 Belgium   BE   Regulated  56010346
15610 2014 Belgium   BE Unregulated  40380694
286   2015 Belgium   BE         ETS  44713916
15810 2015 Belgium   BE   Regulated  57375031
15910 2015 Belgium   BE Unregulated  42854461
317   2016 Belgium   BE         ETS  43655728
16110 2016 Belgium   BE   Regulated  56702848
16210 2016 Belgium   BE Unregulated  43540863
348   2017 Belgium   BE         ETS  43772976
```

I'm grateful for any help concerning these two "rather small" problems.

Thanks in any case,

nordsee

Comment: I agree - a downvote without justification is spineless. That being said, you should make your examples completely reproducible in the future; e.g. your code did not match your example dataset.

Comment: Thanks @Marcinthebox. I had inserted the wrong section of the data. I have adjusted it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace zero values with `NaN`:

```
df_to_plot <- read.table(text = "
 year country iso2      sector emissions
1990 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
1990 Belgium   BE       Total 120484398
1990 Belgium   BE   Regulated  78614107
1990 Belgium   BE Unregulated  41870292
1991 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
1991 Belgium   BE       Total 123544711
1991 Belgium   BE   Regulated  79811521
1991 Belgium   BE Unregulated  43733190
1992 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
1992 Belgium   BE       Total 122657813
1992 Belgium   BE   Regulated  78283962
1992 Belgium   BE Unregulated  44373851
1993 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
1993 Belgium   BE       Total 121557281
1993 Belgium   BE   Regulated  76752290
1993 Belgium   BE Unregulated  44804991
1994 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
1994 Belgium   BE       Total 124938188
1994 Belgium   BE   Regulated  80647991
1994 Belgium   BE Unregulated  44290197
1995 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
1995 Belgium   BE       Total 126082961
1995 Belgium   BE   Regulated  80518704
1995 Belgium   BE Unregulated  45564257
1996 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
1996 Belgium   BE       Total 129583625
1996 Belgium   BE   Regulated  79513349
1996 Belgium   BE Unregulated  50070276
1997 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
1997 Belgium   BE       Total 124046828
1997 Belgium   BE   Regulated  77308936
1997 Belgium   BE Unregulated  46737892
1998 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
1998 Belgium   BE       Total 130285109
1998 Belgium   BE   Regulated  82610050
1998 Belgium   BE Unregulated  47675059
1999 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
1999 Belgium   BE       Total 124745703
1999 Belgium   BE   Regulated  77595053
1999 Belgium   BE Unregulated  47150650
2000 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
2000 Belgium   BE       Total 126794789
2000 Belgium   BE   Regulated  80435088
2000 Belgium   BE Unregulated  46359701
2001 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
2001 Belgium   BE       Total 126129008
2001 Belgium   BE   Regulated  77255899
2001 Belgium   BE Unregulated  48873109
2002 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
2002 Belgium   BE       Total 126444625
2002 Belgium   BE   Regulated  77914653
2002 Belgium   BE Unregulated  48529972
2003 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
2003 Belgium   BE       Total 127953188
2003 Belgium   BE   Regulated  78464806
2003 Belgium   BE Unregulated  49488382
2004 Belgium   BE         ETS         0
2004 Belgium   BE       Total 129040883
2004 Belgium   BE   Regulated  79430967
2004 Belgium   BE Unregulated  49609916
2005 Belgium   BE         ETS  55363232
2005 Belgium   BE       Total 125638203
2005 Belgium   BE   Regulated  77343444
2005 Belgium   BE Unregulated  48294759
2006 Belgium   BE         ETS  54775328
2006 Belgium   BE       Total 124030891
2006 Belgium   BE   Regulated  75869846
2006 Belgium   BE Unregulated  48161044
2007 Belgium   BE         ETS  52795332
2007 Belgium   BE       Total 120611398
2007 Belgium   BE   Regulated  73189198
2007 Belgium   BE Unregulated  47422201
2008 Belgium   BE         ETS  55462028
2008 Belgium   BE       Total 120659008
2008 Belgium   BE   Regulated  71854823
2008 Belgium   BE Unregulated  48804185
2009 Belgium   BE         ETS  46206936
2009 Belgium   BE       Total 107642367
2009 Belgium   BE   Regulated  61048912
2009 Belgium   BE Unregulated  46593455
2010 Belgium   BE         ETS  50103980
2010 Belgium   BE       Total 113582031
2010 Belgium   BE   Regulated  66648934
2010 Belgium   BE Unregulated  46933097
2011 Belgium   BE         ETS  46203056
2011 Belgium   BE       Total 104158641
2011 Belgium   BE   Regulated  61319344
2011 Belgium   BE Unregulated  42839297
2012 Belgium   BE         ETS  43006980
2012 Belgium   BE       Total 101394977
2012 Belgium   BE   Regulated  58934979
2012 Belgium   BE Unregulated  42459997
2013 Belgium   BE         ETS  45231176
2013 Belgium   BE       Total 101970445
2013 Belgium   BE   Regulated  58383554
2013 Belgium   BE Unregulated  43586891
2014 Belgium   BE         ETS  43853144
2014 Belgium   BE       Total  96391039
2014 Belgium   BE   Regulated  56010346
2014 Belgium   BE Unregulated  40380694
2015 Belgium   BE         ETS  44713916
2015 Belgium   BE       Total 100229492
2015 Belgium   BE   Regulated  57375031
2015 Belgium   BE Unregulated  42854461
2016 Belgium   BE         ETS  43655728
2016 Belgium   BE       Total 100243711
2016 Belgium   BE   Regulated  56702848
2016 Belgium   BE Unregulated  43540863  
  ", header = T)


head(df_to_plot)


df_to_plot <- subset(df_to_plot, sector != "Total")
df_to_plot$year <-as.numeric(df_to_plot$year)
names(df_to_plot) <- c("Year", "Country","iso2", "Sector", "Emissions")

cols <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", 
      "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

df_to_plot$Sector <- as.character(df_to_plot$Sector)
df_to_plot$Emissions[df_to_plot$Emissions==0] <- NaN


p <- ggplot(df_to_plot) +
geom_line(aes(x= Year,y= Emissions,group = Sector, color = Sector)) +
labs(x="Year",y="CO2 Emissions",z="",title=paste("Emissions for","Belgium")) + 
xlim(1990,2016) +
theme(plot.margin=unit(c(.5,.5,.5,.5),"cm")) +
scale_color_manual(values = cols)+
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)

print(p)
```

[image]